# How to iterate over a char** without knowing its length

Tags: c, glib

The GLib library gives me a `char**` without any length. How do I iterate over it, printing every string in the array?

I've tried the following code but it only gives me the first string, even though the array contains multiple strings.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <glib.h>

static gchar** input_files = NULL;

static const GOptionEntry command_entries[] = {
        {"input", 'i', G_OPTION_FLAG_NONE, G_OPTION_ARG_STRING_ARRAY, &input_files, "Input files", NULL},
        {NULL}
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    GOptionContext* option_context;
    GError* error;

    option_context = g_option_context_new(NULL);
    g_option_context_add_main_entries(option_context, command_entries, NULL);
    if (!g_option_context_parse(option_context, &argc, &argv, &error)) {
        g_printerr("%s: %s\n", argv[0], error->message);
        return 1;
    }
    g_option_context_free(option_context);

    if (input_files) {
        for (int i = 0; input_files[i]; i++) {
            printf("%s", input_files[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

```sh
$ ./a.out -i One Two Three
One
```

Comment: *The GLib library gives me..* - what exactly in glib is giving you that?

Comment: If there's no explicit length, it's usually terminated by a null pointer, so your loop should work.

Comment: I've edited my question with a full example. As you can see, "One", "Two", "Three" are passed in as arguments and the loop only prints "One".

Comment: Try `./a.out -i One -i Two -i Three` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [GLib documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Commandline-option-parser.html)

> `G_OPTION_ARG_STRING_ARRAY`
>
> The option takes a string argument, **multiple uses** of the option are collected into an array of strings.

(emphasis mine). You have to use the option multiple times to get multiple strings in the array.

```
./a.out -i One -i Two -i Three
```